# Controller's method(http get): optional parameter is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple Controller's method that accepts Id and a `ComplexObject` optionally.

I'm entering this method with `id` parameter via URL (below is code behind URL), but when I'm setting break point inside that method, then `optionalFormData` is not null, but instead it is `FormData` instance with everything (`FirstName`, `SecondName`, `File`) except `Id` (Guid) being null.

I want `optionalFormData` to be null when it is not sent instead of being an instance of `FormData` with `null` values of properties.

Pseudo code:

```
public IActionResult MyView(Guid? id, FormData optionalFormData = null)
{
    if (optionalFormData != null)
    {
        return View(optionalFormData);
    }

    return View(_context.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id.Value));
}


public class FormData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public File File { get; set; }
}

@Html.ActionLink("Enter MyView", "MyView", "MyController", new { id = Model?.Id })
```

I tried doing `FormData? optionalFormData` but it requires C# 8.0

How can I do that at 7.x?

Comment: By using `new { id = Model?.Id }` you **always** pass a value for optionalFormData.  You can't resolve this by using `FormData? optionalFormData`, it will have zero effect.  Better change you ActionLink.

Comment: If you have a property in a class, you will always have it in a class instance. You can however create a `BaseFormData` class with only the ID and have another `FullFormData` class inheriting from it.

Comment: @Nick Why? generated url is: ``/MyController/MyView/401af(...)bb7dc`` ``Better change you ActionLink.`` To what?

Comment: try specify a `[FromBody]` tag before your `FormData optionalFormData`

Comment: `FormData` is a class, so it's intrinsically nullable. C# 8.0 flips the tables a bit and issues warnings in such cases to get the developer to be explicit about nullability (and expands the `?` operator to be applied to things like classes to support that). None of this has anything to do with your issue here.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to provide optional `FormData optionalFormData`? What is your purpose for `MyView Action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core Model Binding, it will create the model instance during binding process, and set the properties one by one. You could not set the model with null if it is not provided.

For a workaround, you may check the model properties one by one to see whether they are default value for non-nullable and null for nullable value.

Try

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault(this object obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return true;

        return obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .All(x => IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetValue(obj)));
    }

    private static bool IsNullOrEmpty(object value)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            return true;

        var type = value.GetType();
        return type.IsValueType
            && Object.Equals(value, Activator.CreateInstance(type));
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
public IActionResult MyView(Guid? id, FormData optionalFormData = null)
{
    if (!optionalFormData.IsNullOrDefault())
    {
        return View(optionalFormData);
    }

    return View(_context.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id.Value));
}
```