# ASP.net : How to pass a null object, instead of an empty one?

Tags: asp.net, forms, entity-framework, null, bind

How can one have a null object, instead of an empty objet (all properties to null) ? More specifically when the given object's name is not in the form.

Here is my example. I'm posting a simple form to my controller. I have some data bound to *p_user*, and *p_password*, but **not to p_info**. I would have expected it to be **null**.

Note : All the objects are **Entities** obtained using a DbFirst Approach with EntityFramework.

Instead, I have the following : [image]

**Form :**

```
<form id="accountForm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("CreateAccount")">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">EMail</label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="p_user.email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" name="p_user.username" class="form-control " type="text" aria-describedby="usernameHelp" placeholder="Enter your username" />
        <small id="usernameHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="p_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Créer</button>
</form>
```

**Controller** :

`public ActionResult CreateAccount(T_User p_user, string p_password, T_UserInfo p_info = null)`

**T_UserInfo** :

```
public partial class T_UserInfo
{
    public int id_user { get; set; }
    public string forname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string avatar_path { get; set; }
    
    public virtual T_User T_User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show the T_UserInfo class code

Comment: I've added the class. It's generated by EntityFramework. I have also added a note about that.

Comment: I found a similar question, apparently it is not possible to indicate a nullable object in the controller method and it is better to validate all the properties of the object to determine if it is really null: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649311/controllers-methodhttp-get-optional-parameter-is-not-null

Comment: Alright. The answer is for asp.Net core, but I'm guessing it is the same for our good old asp.Net. Thanks

Comment: Objects passed to your controller from the view are not Entities, they are serialized JSON objects cast as entities. The form's Model is an object with blank values, that is what will be sent back.